# First appearance of the walk down a black hallway with evenly spaced circles of light?

Tags: first-appearance, cinematography, lighting

[image]

What is the first film or television show to employ this trope:  character walks away down a blackened hallway with overhead light fixtures creating evenly spaced circles of light on the floor?

In most cases, the lights come on one by one as a character walks under them, as in *Cool World*:

[image]

Comment: Purely from memory I'd say "The Prisoner" 1969.

Comment: Um, possibly the one in your first picture, wherever that's from?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Unlikely.  I asked this after I saw the trope used in an old episode of *Twilight Zone*, and it smacks of film noir.

Comment: OP's right, definitely seems like a film noir trope; see minute 2:09 [**here**](https://vimeo.com/136754091) (from *Phantom Lady*, 1944) and I doubt that's even the first instance of it.

Comment: Would images such as [this one](http://www.fingmonkey.com/2012/04/michaels-movie-pick-2-night-of-demon.html) from Night of the Demon qualify? Or are you specifically looking for the spotlight?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - That's from a 2016 movie.

Comment: I would start with German Expressionism.  I can't think of a specific example, but Fritz Lang or Robert Wiene perhaps.  I'm thinking of examples such as the Cabinet of Dr. Caligari where the effect of light was simulated by painting light and shadow on the floor and walls.